# Java - how do I delete a non-empty buckets in google cloud?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to delete buckets in my code and it works only if the bucket is empty.
My deletion code is

```
com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Buckets.Delete delete = storage.buckets().delete(bucketName);
        delete.execute();
```

If the bucket is not empty I get an exception and error message saying the bucket is not empty
I am trying to find a solution with no success in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1beta2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Buckets.Delete.html)

I thought that I can get a list of objects of the bucket's content and then start deleting them but I can't find this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, finally I found the solution as this:

```
 List<StorageObject> storageObjects = new ArrayList();
    torage.Objects.List listObjects = storage.objects().list(bucket);
    Objects objects = listObjects.execute();
    storageObjects.addAll(objects.getItems());
    for (StorageObject storageObject : workBucketObjects) {
           Storage.Objects.Delete delete = storage.objects().delete(bucketName,storageObject.getName());
           delete.execute();
```

}

Comment: I am not 100% sure this would work fine. storage.objects().list(bucket) is a paginated, it returns the first 50 object only so you won't be able to delete the others. Indeed there should be another loop on request to delete all the objects in the buckets as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list

Answer (score 3):

You can use `com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Objects.List` to list the objects in a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Since there have been considerable changes to the Google Cloud Storage API, the above solution is not going to work for every setup (e.g., you're in a Maven project and you only have access to the `com.google.cloud.storage.*` namespace.)

So, my solution is two-fold: (1) Iterate over all the files (2) Delete all the files recursively (3) Delete the bucket itself.

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;

private static void deleteGcsBucket(String projectId, String gcsBucketName) {
  StorageOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = StorageOptions.newBuilder();
  StorageOptions storageOptions = optionsBuilder.setProjectId(projectId).build();
  Storage storage = storageOptions.getService();

  Iterable<Blob> blobs = storage.list(gcsBucketName, 
      Storage.BlobListOption.prefix("")).iterateAll();
  for (Blob blob : blobs) {
    blob.delete(Blob.BlobSourceOption.generationMatch());
  }

  storage.delete(gcsBucketName, 
      Storage.BucketSourceOption.userProject(projectId));
}
```